# PHP - Logical operator with IF/Else statement test not working correctly

Tags: php, osclass

Code from: `oc-content/themes/realestate/item.php`

I have this piece of PHP code which is part of a 'framework' called [OSClass](http://osclass.org/). Basically, I am trying to 'hide' the user (the publisher of the advert) name to non-logged in users. In other words, only if a user is logged in, only then they can see if the publisher users advert.

I found out that I need to add this piece of code `osc_is_web_user_logged_in()`, which has worked perfectly for another section, however, due to the `else` statement, the publishers name is still displaying...

How can I amend the else statement? I could remove the else statement, but I'm worried it will 'break' something and I am unsure what `osc_item_user_id()` does... Do I add another if statement within the else statement (complete PHP newbie here).

```
<div class="ico-author ico"></div>                  
    <?php if( osc_item_user_id() != null && osc_is_web_user_logged_in()  ){ ?> 
          <?php echo osc_item_contact_name(); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
          <?php echo osc_item_contact_name(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing the same thing in the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: Why do you go in and out of `<?php` on each line?

Comment: @Barmar that's how the code was. All I've done is added is the && statement on the end :)

Comment: *If user is logged in output contact name else output contact name.* - Man, that's a real head scratcher... =_=;;

Comment: If you do the same thing in the `if` and `else` blocks, it makes no difference what you put in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should simple write:

```
<div class="ico-author ico"></div>                  
    <?php if( osc_item_user_id() != null && osc_is_web_user_logged_in()  ){ ?> 
          <?php echo osc_item_contact_name(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

As you don't want to display publisher name when user is not logged, you don't need have else section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `else if` statement.

```
if (osc_item_user_id() != null && osc_is_web_user_logged_in())
{
    <?php echo osc_item_contact_name(); ?>
}
else if (user non logged)
{
    // your stuff 
}
else
{
    <?php echo osc_item_contact_name(); ?>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this now and get back to you